# How do I create a link from a sprite image?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/herrturtur/2K8hZ/11/) I'm trying to create a link that covers the entirety of the sprite image. For some reason though, the height and width attributes of `a` don't seem to work.

What can I do to create links from sprite images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2K8hZ/14/). The link covers the whole image now and this is done by turning the link into a block element with display: block like many other answers above state. I also added the id selector to all your other selectors and moved the selector and declaration with where the actual background image is being declared to the top. The reason for this, is that the li-element's background-position were overwritten because of lack of [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and due to the order of your css declarations.

Answer (score 4):

add `display:inline-block` or `display:block` to `a` for dimensions to work. dimensions don't take effect for `inline` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
// Code shifted to the end.
```

Where, CSS is like this:

```
.sprite-sp1{ 
    background-position: 0 0; 
    width: 242px; 
    height: 244px; 
} 
.sprite-sp1 a{
    width: 242px;
    height: 244px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.sprite-sp2{ 
    background-position: 0 -294px; 
    width: 241px; 
    height: 244px;
} 
#container li {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/iDrt8.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

**EDIT** Edited to make the sprite clickable. The new code shall be:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li><a href="http://google.com/"><span class="sprite-sp1"></span>test</a></li>
    <li><span class="sprite-sp1"></span></li>
</ul>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block;` to `a`, it will work then...